# 3-digit chopping vs 3-digit rounding and relative error

Tags: decimal-expansion

Are my calculations below about 3-digit chopping, 3-digit rounding, and relative errors correct?

> given 4/5 * 1/3:
>
> Exact value: 0.2666666666666667 
> 3-digit chopping: 0.266, its relative error: 0.0025
> 3-digit rounding: 0.266, its relative error: 0.0025
>
> For another example, (1/3 - 3/11) + 3/20:
> Exact value: 0.2106060606060606
> 3-digit chopping: 0.210, its relative error: 0.0029
> 3-digit rounding: 0.211, its relative error: 0.002
>
> 3rd example, (1/3 + 3/11) - 3/20:
> Exact value: 0.4560606060606061
> 3-digit chopping: 0.456, its relative error: 0.000133
> 3-digit rounding: 0.456, its relative error: 0.00233

Comment: In the second and third example the values are swapped. And in the third you cannot chop or round to $0.455$.

Comment: @gammatester thanks, I have fixed the issue based on your comment. For the 3rd one, why can I not chop to 0.456? - okay, 0.455 you mean, I have changed it. please review now.

Comment: @gammatester is the relative errors correct?

Comment: I assume you always use absolute values, otherwise you have to be more specific. In the second example rounding gives an relative error $0.00187$. This may be rounded to $0.002$ but I strongly suggest that you use a single consistent format for your error values. In the third ex. you have only adjusted the value but not the error for rounding.

Comment: In the first, your "exact value" is not correct.  You cannot represent the exact value of $\frac 4{15}$ with any finite decimal.  It is a rounded value, but with a larger number of decimals than $3$.  The same applies to the other examples.  When you say exact value you should mean it.  Then the three digit rounding is wrong.  It should be $0.267$ and the relative error is smaller than chopping to $0.266$